# Подключение платежной системы Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, php7, платежи

Всем привет, подскажите как подключить платежную систему Юmoney (какие советуете для ип) к своему сайту Laravel. Есть ли руководство? А именно я бы хотела понять как обрабатывать обратный ответ сервера и записывать данные в бд.

Comment: Смотря откуда планируется принимать оплату. Я бы использовал киви, например. По подключению и у тех и у тех все подробно расписано в документации

Answer (score 1):

Для подключения Yoomoney к вашему Laravel проекту используйте пакет [yoomoney/yookassa-sdk-php](https://github.com/yoomoney/yookassa-sdk-php).

Там вы найдете достаточно подробную документацию по интеграции требуемых решений.